# Prove that a Mersenne number $2^{n−1}(2^{n} −1)$ such that $2^n −1$ is not prime must be abundant.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Prove that a Mersenne number $2^{n−1}(2^{n} −1)$ such that $2^n −1$ is not prime must be abundant.
My attempt so far

$\sigma(2^{n-1})\sigma(2^n-1)=(2^n-1)\sigma((2^x-1)(2^{x(y-1)}+2^{x(y-2)}\dots+2^2+1))$ If $x \mid n$ then $2^x-1 \mid 2^n-1$ since you can factor $2^n-1$ for as many factors of $n$ so $2^n-1$ must have at least as many divisors as $n$ thus $\sigma(2^{n-1})\sigma(2^n-1) \geq 2n$

Comment: The point is that $\sigma(2^n-1)\ge 1+(2^x-1)+(2^n-1)>2n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear how you are using the number of divisors to conclude something about the sum of the divisors.

Instead, you can use the fact that, if an integer $m$ is not prime, then $\sigma(m)\ge m+2$ since $m$ is a divisor, and $m$ must have a divisor greater than $1$ if $m$ is not prime.

Hence, if $2^n-1$ is not prime, then
$$
\sigma(2^n-1) \ge 2^n+1
$$
and so 
$$
\sigma(2^{n-1}(2^n-1)) \ge (2^n-1)(2^n+1) = 2^{2n}-1 > 
2^{2n}-2^n = 2^n(2^n-1)= 2\left(2^{n-1}(2^n-1\right)).$$
Thus, $2^{n-1}(2^n-1)$ is abundant.

One way to look at this is that powers of $2$ are very nearly abundant, and so it doesn't take much to push it ``over the edge" into abundancy.